# Microsoft Hyper-v Server 2008 R2, is it realy free?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/hyper-v-server/buy.aspx

Is this product truly free to use in a commercial environment? I plan on migrating from ESXi and this seems like the ideal solution.

Comment: Yes.

Possible duplicate of this question: 
http://serverfault.com/questions/113339/will-hyper-v-always-be-free

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 is free.

Download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3512#system-requirements).

Comment: Upvote. Keep in mind though, that even though the hypervisor is free, that doesn't mean all your guest OSes are free too. ;)